# SubSonic 3.0 , I'm missing SubSonic.Query

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

I probably missed something in the .tt configuration for some reason my intellisense when I type SubSonic.Query or Query = new Query(DB.Table) is not highlighting and giving me an error. Anybody has a problem like this? appreciate any help.

thanks

Comment: Hint: whenever you write something like "is [...] giving me an error" in a question, you should always say *what the error is*. You have important information which can help us to help you. Don't keep it to yourself! See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Is it specifically SubSonic.Query, All SubSonic or all intellisense?
Try cleaning the solution followed by a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added a reference to the SubSonic assembly?